# Jquery copy the html of a page as it would have been before a jquery slider had started

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If you have a webpage and on that page is a jquery slider like nivo slider.  At some point with jQuery i'd like to be able to copy the html of the page as it would have been before nivo slider started.

I wanted to do this because i don't want all of the inline styles and numbers that the slider puts on the divs and images while it's animating to be captured in the .html().

Is there a method out there for grabbing the static html of a webpage?

Comment: Ha? And most are the tags are way too general...

Comment: And what's the purpose for doing this?

Comment: Why do you need the HTML source code?

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery's load function on the page you're on. That will load all the HTML but won't run any scripts on it.

**Something like**

```
$("#copy-page").click(function(e) {
    var href = window.location.href;
    $("#result").load(href);
});
```

If you need to save it to a variable, you can use `$.get()` instead.

```
$("#copy-page").click(function(e) {
    var href = window.location.href;
    var content;
    $.get(href, function(data) {
        content = data;
        alert(content);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

- You could capture the html of the page before the slider initialized and save it into a variable for later use. That way you'll not get any changes made to the page after that.
- You could delete the slider stuff from your html after you retrieved it. Something like that should work:

  var html = $('body').clone().find('slider').remove().end().html();